# Drupal 8 REST resource POST method

Tags: rest, drupal-8

I need help to implement a custom REST API using POST method in Drupal 8.

I have a REST resource plugin class, and a get() method in it.
I am able to access this resource through GET method and is working fine.

I have a post() method in the same class, but is unable to access the resource through POST method, even though "POST" is displayed when viewing through "REST UI" module.

[image: REST UI Settings page]

But when accessing through POST method it displayed following error.

```
{"message":"No route found for \u0022POST \/iot\/location\/\u0022: Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)"}
```

I am using POSTMAN Chrome extension and the screenshot is below
[image: Testing REST API]

I have used following blog to write the REST API and my code is almost same as the code shown in this blog post

http://enzolutions.com/articles/2014/12/16/how-to-create-a-rest-resource-in-drupal-8/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm also struggling with creating a custom POST endpoint.  Unfortunately there seems to be no code or tutorials about creating a custom POST endpoint, everything focuses on the existing Core entity/{entity_type}/{entity}.  I think the issue is with not understanding the 'serialization_class' and 'deriver' keys in the @RestResource annotation.  I hope I can provide an answer here after figuring it out...

Comment: Have you cleared caches? Thanks.

Comment: Have you followed the docs from https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview? Also, what version of Drupal 8.x are you using (8.1.x, 8.2.x)? Maybe it's a bug of the rest_ui module. Have you tried to create create the yml file yourself wihout the rest_ui help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set `uri_paths` in your REST Resource including "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create".

For example you may have something like this:

```
/**
 * My REST Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "my_rest_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("My REST Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/my_rest/resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

To POST to the above resource you would use the endpoint `/my_rest_resource`. If you're wanting to POST to `/my_rest/resource` instead then add the link relations entry:

```
/**
 * My REST Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "my_rest_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("My REST Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/my_rest/resource",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/my_rest/resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

You may need to clear the cache after adding https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create. I've found that GET may work as expected with the first example while POST fails with the error "405 method not allowed".

The wording on this topic in Drupal's documentation ( https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/restful-web-services-api-overview ) could be a little clearer.